# Asking questions on puzzle creation

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

What are the rules for questions on puzzle-creation?

Should we ask them on Puzzling SE or on the meta?
What are their scope? (I'm afraid a question like "How do I write a good quiz?" will be too broad)

Are questions asking for good books/websites on puzzle-writing on-scope?

Comment: Your example does seem too generalised, however very specific questions like 'how do I check this sudoku for the unique character of the answer' would be perfectly acceptable. By any chance, is 'LookingForAName' the same person as 'NeedAName'? I couldn't help but notice...

Answer (score 8):

> What are the rules for questions on puzzle-creation?

They are perfectly on-topic on the main site. The site is for `puzzles and puzzle related questions`. Your question  falls under `puzzle related questions` and therefore is on-topic on the the main site. In fact, we have a tag named [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) whose excerpt reads `A question about the creation and development of puzzles.` Currently, it has 71 questions.

> Should we ask them on Puzzling SE or on the meta?

Definitely on puzzling.se. The meta is for discussion about the the main site. If your question is about puzzles in general ask them on the main site. However, if your question is about puzzles on puzzling.se, you should probably be asking them on meta.

> What are their scope?

I think, as long as they are puzzle related and not too broad or too subjective they should be fine. While  `How do I write a good riddle?` will be too broad, you can narrow it down by specifying what you are looking for. Example:[1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/tips-wanted-on-creating-a-successful-short-riddle-with-a-unique-answer-without-a?s=2|3.1892),[2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/how-do-i-write-a-solid-riddle?s=1|3.5349),[3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-you-come-up-with-a-good-classic-rhyme-riddle)

> Are questions asking for good books/websites on puzzle-writing on-scope?

I'm not sure about this one. Personally, I think `what are good sites for puzzles` should be too broad. But, if you narrow them down (for example by mentioning what type of puzzles you are looking for), it should be on-topic. Again, this is personal opinion. I do not know about the community's stance on this.

Answer (score 5):

This question I can answer:

> Should we ask them on Puzzling SE or on the meta?

This is definitely not supposed to be on meta so if it's on topic it should be on Puzzling SE. The meta is for asking questions about Puzzling SE. These kinds of questions are not about the website but are "real questions" and therefore should be on Puzzling SE.